# Is there any way to execute a function when a function is defined?

Tags: javascript, function

Say I have this code:

```
const old = Function

Function = function(...args) {
    console.log('Hello!')
    return old.apply(this, args)
}
```

I can then use the `Function` constructor like so:

```
new Function('return 5')
```

Which logs `"Hello"` to the console, before returning a new function which just returns *5*. This is what I want, but I want to know how, or even if it's possible to, do this for *normally* defined functions:

```
function fn () {
    return 5
}
```

And I want this function to do the same as last one (`new Function...`). Now, I wouldn't be surprised if this isn't even possible, but if it is, how would I do it?

Comment: It seems people are confused about your aim here, so, just to clarify, you want your `console.log` to run whenever *any function, anywhere* is defined, not the specific function in your example. Correct?

Comment: You might be able to do something with [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), but the functions would have to be properties of an object.

Comment: @Touffy That's right.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I've had a look at Proxies, but from what I can tell they, like my example, only work when creating a function via the `Function` constructor, and not using the `function` keyword.

Comment: As I mentioned, they would have to be properties of an object. Those properties could be created using the `function` keyword, like `var obj = { this.getMonkey = function () { return "No monkey :("; }; };`, then I think you could use proxies to intercept the `getMonkey` call and inject whatever else you wanted. But no, not on a bare, global function like the one in your example (which is one reason it was a comment and not an answer :)).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Oh, I see what you mean - well, I guess that might still be useful anyway.